# reuse DialogFragment anywhere

Tags: android, instance, android-dialogfragment

I am developing an app with a few functionalities and whenever there is some error happens in a functionality, an DialogFragment with two buttons will be shown:

1. Press Positive button to do something
2. Press Negative button to dismiss itself.

And if an error happens and we have a ErrorManager class to show the error:

```
public class ErrorManager {
    public static showError(int errorType, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        switch(errorType) {
            case 0:
                 new ErrorDialog().setTitle()
                                 .setMessage()
                                 .setPositveButton(()->{
                                       // dosomething when the positive button is clicked
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),.....);
                                 }.show(fragmentManager)
            ...
            default:
            break;              
    }
}
```

The ErrorManager can be called not only inside the FragmentActivity but anywhere where the `FragmentManager` can be passed.

and the ErrorDialog is something like:

```
private ButtonFunction F;
public ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public interface ButtonFunction {
        void doSomething();
    }
    public ErrorDialog() {

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        // set the title in the bundle
    }

    public void setPositveButton(Function f) {
       this.f = f
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
    Button positiveButton = view.findViewById(R.id.postive);
    positiveButton.setOnClickListener(v->{
                    if (f != null) {
                       f.doSomething()
                    }
                    dismiss();
                });
    }
}
```

By doing this, we can just show the error dialog from ErrorManager class and provide different implementation when the positive button is clicked. Until we turn on the **Don't keep Activities** from Develop option where the Activity/Fragment view have been destroyed so the "ButtonFunction" is lost.

I have tried the `setretaininstance(true)` but it works for the orientation change.

I am not sure if set `static ButtonFunction f` will work or cause any memory leak if the f implementation contains some ParentActivity reference.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Xml for custom dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/genericDialog"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Your Custom Message"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/negativeCLick"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/positiveClick"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negativeCLick"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Java code custom Dialog

```
    // 3 Params: 1st- Activity, 2nd- Dialog Message, 3-New Activity of action you want to do.
    public static void showDialogWithYesNo(Activity activity, String msg, Class gotoActivity) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        int layout_parms;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            layout_parms = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            layout_parms = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }

        new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                layout_parms,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.generic_dialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogMessage);
        text.setText(msg);

        TextView dialogBtn_cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.negativeCLick);
        dialogBtn_cancel.setText("No");
        dialogBtn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        TextView dialogBtn_okay = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.positiveClick);
        dialogBtn_okay.setText("Yes");
        dialogBtn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

// Add actions as per your need here for positive response
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, gotoActivity);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

> How to use the above dialog

```
    //1: Activity.this will your Activity Name.this 
    //2: Your Message you want to display in your dialog
    //3: The Activity you want to open when a user press yes. eg: NewAcitivity.class

    showDialogWithYesNo(Activity.this, "Do you want to exit ?", Activity.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems this Dialog positive button click is tied with only one implementation. My requirement is that different implementations can be provided in the click.

Comment: Hi @user703232 you can use interface to do different implementations, let me know if you need it. I can create and share.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to implement it:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    Context context;
    String title, msg, positiveBtnText, negativeBtnText;
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClickListner, negativeClickListner, itemClickListner;
    DialogInterface.OnKeyListener keyListener;
    String[] items;
    public static boolean mIsDisplayed = false;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private TextView selectedText;
    boolean isPrivacyPopUp = false;
    Date final_firebase_date = null;
    private boolean alertSizeFlag, alertDueDate;
    private int viewAlert;
    private Button postiveButton, negativeButton;

    public AlertDialogFragment() {
    }


    public static AlertDialogFragment getInstance(Context context, String title, String msg, String positiveBtnText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClickListner, String negativeBtnText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeClickListner, DialogInterface.OnKeyListener keyListener, Date final_firebase_date, boolean isPrivacyPopUP) {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.context = context;
        alertDialogFragment.title = title;
        alertDialogFragment.msg = msg;
        alertDialogFragment.positiveBtnText = positiveBtnText;
        alertDialogFragment.negativeBtnText = negativeBtnText;
        alertDialogFragment.positiveClickListner = positiveClickListner;
        alertDialogFragment.negativeClickListner = negativeClickListner;
        alertDialogFragment.keyListener = keyListener;
        alertDialogFragment.isPrivacyPopUp = isPrivacyPopUP;
        alertDialogFragment.final_firebase_date = final_firebase_date;
        return alertDialogFragment;
    }

    public static AlertDialogFragment getInstance(Context context, String title, String msg, String positiveBtnText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClickListner, String negativeBtnText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeClickListner, DialogInterface.OnKeyListener keyListener) {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.context = context;
        alertDialogFragment.title = title;
        alertDialogFragment.msg = msg;
        alertDialogFragment.positiveBtnText = positiveBtnText;
        alertDialogFragment.negativeBtnText = negativeBtnText;
        alertDialogFragment.positiveClickListner = positiveClickListner;
        alertDialogFragment.negativeClickListner = negativeClickListner;
        alertDialogFragment.keyListener = keyListener;
        alertDialogFragment.isPrivacyPopUp = false;
        return alertDialogFragment;
    }

    //Create custom Constructor with parameter

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (isPrivacyPopUp) {
            TextView textPrivacyMsg = ((TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message));
            if (textPrivacyMsg != null) {
                textPrivacyMsg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                textPrivacyMsg.setText(xxxxxxxx.addClickablePartForPrivacy1(context,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.privacy_popup_note),
                        R.string.privacy,
                        R.string.privacy_link, R.color.blue, final_firebase_date, alertDialog), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            }
        }

        if (alertSizeFlag == true) {
            if (getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
                if(LandingScreenPhoneActivity.isTablet(getActivity())){
                    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(CommonBindingUtils.getRelativeWidthInPX(150), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    PreferencesManager.getInstance().putBoolean(ALERT_FLAG, false);
                }
                else{
                    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(CommonBindingUtils.getRelativeWidthInPX(280),WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    PreferencesManager.getInstance().putBoolean(ALERT_FLAG, false);
                }

            }
        }

        if (alertDueDate == true) {
            if (getDialog().getWindow() != null ) {
                if(LandingScreenPhoneActivity.isTablet(getActivity())){
                    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(CommonBindingUtils.getRelativeWidthInPX(150), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   // getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(CommonBindingUtils.getRelativeWidthInPX(150), CommonBindingUtils.getRelativeHeightInPX(150));

                }
                else{
                    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(CommonBindingUtils.getRelativeWidthInPX(280),WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                }

            }
        }

        //Crash fix #178
        if (alertDialog!=null){
            negativeButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            postiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        }


        if (postiveButton != null) {
            postiveButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.new_colorPrimary));
        }
        if (negativeButton != null) {
            negativeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.new_colorPrimary));
        }

        // getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(200,200);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int checkedItem = -1;


        alertSizeFlag = PreferencesManager.getInstance().getBoolean(ALERT_FLAG);

        alertDueDate = PreferencesManager.getInstance().getBoolean(DUE_DATE_ALERT);

        if (items != null && selectedText != null) {
            checkedItem = Arrays.asList(items).indexOf(selectedText.getText().toString());
        }


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.customalertstyle)
                // set dialog icon
                // set Dialog Title
                .setTitle(title)
                // Set Dialog Message
                .setItems(items, itemClickListner)
                .setMessage(msg)
                // positive button
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, positiveClickListner)
                .setOnKeyListener(keyListener)
                .setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, negativeClickListner);

        if (viewAlert != 0 && alertDueDate == true) {
            builder.setView(viewAlert);
        }

        if (selectedText != null) {
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, checkedItem, itemClickListner);
        }
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        if (isPrivacyPopUp) {
            Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
            window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        }

        return alertDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        //to catch the exception while app is in background and dialog
        try {
            super.show(manager, tag);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
        xxxxxxxx.resetBellyCount();
        mIsDisplayed = false;
        clearReferences();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);

        xxxxxxxx.resetBellyCount();
        mIsDisplayed = false;
        xxxxxxxx.resetBellyCount();
        mIsDisplayed = false;
        clearReferences();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        clearReferences();
    }

    private void clearReferences() {
        context = null;
        title = null;
        msg = null;
        positiveBtnText = null;
        negativeBtnText = null;
        positiveClickListner = negativeClickListner = itemClickListner = null;
        keyListener = null;
        items = null;
        alertDialog = null;
        selectedText = null;
        final_firebase_date = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Venky, will the "positiveClickListner" be null if the fragment has been re-created due to memory claiming?

Comment: @user703232 No we didn't face such issue for this dialog we used this across whole project. But the context passing to dialog is mattered more.